# Is there a way to link the Xul javascript files in my Eclipse-javascript os it can show the auto-complete while I'm typing?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, xul

Is there a way to link the Xul javascript files in my Eclipse-javascript os it can show the auto-complete while I'm typing?

Comment: what do you want?(it is not clear to me)

Comment: @Thariama I want Eclipse-javascript to show autocomplete for my code, like the Eclise for Java does.. For instance, if I type "windows.c" it should show "window.close()" as an option of what I want, and with a <enter> press it autocomplete for me.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the answer is just no.